# How to set database, server, username and password in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to set the database name, server name, username and password in Laravel via an html form (similar to the way that this can be done in WordPress). Is there any way to do this with Laravel?

Comment: you can build a form in html and use php to generate .env file, but why you should do that? Since most Laravel project are customize to the customer and the developer will setup .env file once for the production release.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to do it in 2 ways in Laravel:

1) Go to `<projectname>/config/database.php` and search for `'connections' =>`

2) Set it in `.env` file on the root.

Comment: ya that i know . my question is like wordpress form. is it possible or not .

Comment: Nope, every framework has its own style so it's not possible like wordpress. Though you can set in globally by changing in `.env` file.

Answer (score 3):

1. go to .env file in the root of your project (must enable show hidden file)
2. if you are using mySql database find these three line or if not exist add this three line into .env file

   - DB_DATABASE=your_database_name
   - DB_USERNAME=your_database_username
   - DB_PASSWORD=your_database_password

for example :

- DB_DATABASE=college
- DB_USERNAME=root
- DB_PASSWORD=password

after doing these work, run this command again "php artisan serve"

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own AdminPanel where you get all config values from the .env file, put them in a form and write them back to the file. Make sure to delete the AdminPanel after the configuration because it's a big security issue.

Comment: ,i asked this question only for curiosity.any way thank you